# CodeMirror textarea.getAttribute is not a function error in mvc3 application

Tags: razor, codemirror

I'm using CodeMirror in my ASP.NET MVC 3 application,
CodeMirror's version is up to date(2.34)

my `textarea` looks like this:

```
@Html.TextAreaFieldFor(s => s.Data.CodeBehind, htmlAttributes: new Dictionary<string, object> { { "class", "textbox codeBehind nffp-code" } })
```

I use CodeMirror like this:

```
var a = CodeMirror.fromTextArea($code, {
        lineNumbers: true,
        matchBrackets: true,
        mode: "text/x-csharp"
});
```

where `$code` is

```
var $code = jQuery('.nffp-code', $root);
```

And after page load I have this error:

> TypeError: textarea.getAttribute is not a function
>   codemirror.js
>   Line 2209
>   textarea.getAttribute("autofocus") != null && hasFocus == document.body;

I used this manual for using CodeMirror:
[manual](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2011/06/10/using-codemirror-to-add-c-syntax-highlighting-to-an-editable-html-textarea.aspx)

Even thought, I'm a total noob in JS, I guess it's hard to do it wrong, still I did.

Any Ideas how to fix the problem?

Comment: `code`    var a = CodeMirror.fromTextArea($code, { `code`

    
that was the problem, should be

`code`    CodeMirror.fromTextArea($code.get(0), ``code

Comment: Brilliant, just the hint i needed.  Thanks for posting.

Comment: Just to edit @inlines's comment's view: 
`var a = CodeMirror.fromTextArea($code, {... ` should be `CodeMirror.fromTextArea($code.get(0), ...`

Comment: @inlines Note the backtick (\`) is not used in English, use apostrophes (') for that. Will prevent your formatting from getting screwed up. So `it's`, not ``it`s``.

Answer (score 10):

You need to use `document.getElementById()` instead of the jQuery lookup.

Comment: Although this may answer the question, providing
additional information and code samples would significantly improve its long-term
value.  Please [edit] your answer to complete it.

Comment: Poster indicates they're a JavaScript newbie, so please explain the distinction between the results of a jQuery lookup and what is returned by `Document.getElementById()` (and how to convert one to the other).

Answer (score 2):

```
document.getElementById('contents'); //returns a HTML DOM Object

var contents = $('#contents');  //returns a jQuery Object
```

In jQuery, to get the same result as `document.getElementById()`, you can access the jQuery Object and get the first element in the object (Remember JavaScript objects act similar to associative arrays).

```
var contents = $('#contents')[0]; //returns a HTML DOM Object
```